# Select/Insert/Update/Delete Excel 2007 File and C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel

I am using `DataGridView` and i am binding my Excel file to `DataGridView`.

I am able to read from the Excel file as well as insert to that file using `DataGridView`. But I am not able to delete and update that file.

It's giving an error that says:

> Deleting data in a linked table is not supported by this ISAM.

Is there any other method to perform these operation in an Excel file using `DataGridView`. Or simply how can I delete and update a record in an Excel file using `DataGridView` in C#.

Comment: You can load the data, modify it and then just export the DataGridView to Excel using Microsoft Office Object Library overriding the old file.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that a normal delete (like from access for example) is not supported as mentioned [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819)  by microsoft, i think you should consider using MS Access as your data source since it is much easier to deal with or you have to work around a different approach like deleting the while file and recreating it each time for both deleting and updating (not recommended).

In the page I linked they said the best way is to empty the cells for the row u need to delete.

good Luck